# I get this Error : PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol “END” when expecting one of the following

Tags: plsql

If someone needs more information about what procedure or function need to do I would gladly explain them.
This is my package spec where I declared function and procedure :

```
create or replace PACKAGE SEMIR AS 

  /* TODO enter package declarations (types, exceptions, methods etc) here */ 
  PROCEDURE set_sal;

  FUNCTION emp_info(empno NUMBER)
  return VARCHAR2;
END SEMIR;
```

and my package body :

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY SEMIR AS




  PROCEDURE set_sal AS
  v_manager_sal number;
  v_sal number;
  v_grade number;
  v_empno number;
  BEGIN

    SELECT sal INTO v_sal FROM EMP1;
    SELECT grade INTO v_grade FROM EMP1;
    UPDATE EMP1
    SET oldsal = v_sal;
      IF (v_sal<=3000) THEN
      SELECT MAX(sal) INTO v_sal FROM EMP1
      WHERE grade = grade;

      SELECT sal into v_manager_sal FROM EMP1 WHERE job ='MANAGER' AND
       empno = mgr;
        IF(v_sal-100>v_manager_sal)
        THEN
        UPDATE EMP1
        SET sal = sal-(sal-100-v_sal);
        END IF;
      END IF;
  END set_sal;



  FUNCTION emp_info(empno NUMBER)
  return VARCHAR2 AS
  v_mgr number;
  BEGIN
  SELECT mgr INTO v_mgr
  FROM EMP1;
    IF (v_mgr IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
    SELECT mgr INTO empno
    FROM EMP1
    WHERE empno=mgr;
      IF (mgr IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
      SELECT mgr INTO empno
      FROM EMP1
      WHERE empno = mgr;

        RETURN 'EMPLOYEE:'|| ename || ',' || job;
        ELSE
        RETURN job;
        END IF;
      END IF;
  END emp_info;


END SEMIR;
```

I get error in package body but I dont know what is wrong. Person who gave me this to do also told me that this could be done using cursors too but i hope i could get this working. Regards

Comment: There is only one `IF` but two `END IF` in `set_sal` procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce that error but I do see this error:

```
Error: PLS-00403: expression 'EMPNO' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement
Line: 41
Text: SELECT mgr INTO empno
```

Which is caused by trying to assign a value to a IN parameter.  IN parameters are passed by reference and cannot be modified.

```
  ...
  FUNCTION emp_info(empno NUMBER)   --Defaults to an IN parameter.
  return VARCHAR2 AS
  v_mgr number;
  BEGIN
  SELECT mgr INTO v_mgr
  FROM EMP1;
    IF (v_mgr IS NOT NULL)
    THEN
    SELECT mgr INTO empno           --Trying to modify the IN parameter.
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In parameters are meant to be used as supplied value only and your requirement will fulfil IN OUT mode parameter.But it is recommended no to use out mode in function,so better to use a different variable other than in parameter variable.